# New to C++, would like to create a background thread in MFC application

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, mfc

I have looked through a few examples but I am not finding a simple way to create a background thread in an existing C++ MFC application that I have been tasked with modifying.

I looked at this post --> [Multithreading: Creating Worker Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69644x60.aspx) but this code doesn't work out of the box.  Since I am new to C++ I need more explanation and this article is assuming experience that I don't have with C++.

I am trying to achieve what I have working in the provided C# example below...

This code creates a NEW file once a minute but writes to this file, potentially, several hundred times before that minute elapses and another file is created.  I based the file name on the date and time so each file name is unique.  There is one header row which contains the items from an array of wavelengths and that is written to each file once while subsequent lines of the data I want to store are written many times.  This is the value rawData that is passed in.  You can assume that data is an array of integers or similar.  ProcessHeader happens only once per file creation.

```
private static double[] wavelengths;
private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
private static string fileNameAndPath = "";
private int count = 0;

private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new file once a minute
    fileNameAndPath = string.Format(@"C:\MyData_{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.csv", DateTime.Now);
    var myFile = File.Create(fileNameAndPath);
    myFile.Close();
}

private void ProcessHeader()
{
    fileNameAndPath = string.Format(@"C:\Data_{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.csv", DateTime.Now);
    var myFile = File.Create(fileNameAndPath);
    myFile.Close();
    string[] header = new string[] { string.Join(", ", wavelengths) };
    File.AppendAllLines(fileNameAndPath, header);
}

private void ShowDateTimeAndCount()
{
    // Open the file > add the date and time at the top > add a header row > add the data
    File.AppendAllText(fileNameAndPath, String.Format("Run Date: {0}\tCount: {1}{2}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), ++count, Environment.NewLine));
}

private void LogData(double[] rawData)
{
    // Create initial fileName
    if (fileNameAndPath.Length == 0)
    {
        ProcessHeader();
    }

    ShowDateTimeAndCount();

    // Detail row
    string[] data = new string[] { string.Join(", ", rawData) };
    File.AppendAllLines(fileNameAndPath, data);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Background Worker
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

private void backgroundWorkerAcquisition_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // BEGIN - run once a minute
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
    // END
}
```

Can this be done with C++ MFC?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to work with a timer, which is available in MFC apps.  However, I think you need to explain exactly what it is you want, rather than, comparing to code you know works.

Comment: Code has additional detail added.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted as an example uses a timer, not a background thread. So your link to the MFC threading functions is not relevant. To duplicate the timer approach in an MFC program you call SetTimer in any CWnd derived class and you add a message handler in that class for WM_TIMER. Your message handler function will be called periodically.

Comment: The above code uses a timer that is executed from a background thread object.